# What are these black dotted lines?

Tags: objects

In *Object Mode* I sometimes see these black dotted lines starting at some of my objects and ending in some random spot in the space.

What are they, how do I manipulate them, and why?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are called "Relationship Lines" Normally, they show relationships between an object and its parent, and an object and it constraints. they can be turned off under *options* (<kbd>N</kbd>) *display >  relationship lines*

[image]

Comment: Just curious, where did you find the term "indicating lines"? I've always heard them referred to as "relationship lines".

Comment: fixed sorry bout that.

Answer (score 9):

In Blender 2.8 you can reach it through this arrow down button (Viewport Overlays) in the viewport
[image]