# Is there a way to hide the path that a hook modifier draws on the 3D view?

Tags: modifiers, interface, 3d-view

I have a scene with an absurd amount of hooks (on the order of thousands). This, of course, clutters my scene quite badly.

I was unable to find a way to hide the paths that hooks show linking the parent to the child. I could of course just make it invisible but then the effect of the modifier is lost.

[image: cluttered scene]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are these block dotted lines?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33242/what-are-these-block-dotted-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those paths are called 'relationship lines', and can be toggled on and off here:

[image: relationship lines]