# I have accidentally toggled something to show some weird dotted lines

Tags: splines

I have just accidentally toggled on some weird dotted lines. Any idea how to turn these off. P.S. the model was imported from Fusion 360.

[image]

Comment: Object parts are parented to empties. This is often the case when importing from some formats or tools. This is not something you have toggled.

Comment: Thanks so much....thats it

Comment: @batFinger Right, didn't see that this was a duplicate.

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33242/what-are-these-block-dotted-lines

Answer (score 1):

These are relationship lines which display the relationship between parented objects. You can disable this in the viewport overlay settings.

[image]