# Dotted lines and crosshairs in imported .dae

Tags: pose-mode, dae

I'm pretty new to blender, so it might be a stupid question but I can't find a solution/explanation for this online.

I imported a character file from a game into blender, in the .dae format, since the original file was a animation before I converted into .dae, I would assume it came with the first frame pose, anyways... there are this dotted lines and crosshairs around the whole model, I would assume that they are the bones (because they are conveniently placed where the bones should be), and I should be able to change the character pose using them, but I can't find a way to move them with the model, it only moves the crossair that I clicked. What do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: Relationship lines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33242/what-are-these-block-dotted-lines and empties (at joint locations) rather than bones.  IIRC there could be an option between armature (bones) and empties in importer.

Comment: @batFINGER How do you do that?

Comment: @RayMairlot Yes, but why are they there if they're not moving the model?